# Sequelize Query to get sum group by some specific values in one column

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Model

```js
const Productions=sequelize.define("Productions",{
        rpt_date:{
            type:DataTypes.DATE,
        },
        unit:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:false
        },
        commodity:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:false
        },
        quantity:{
            type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
    })

    return Productions;
}
```

Inside unit field there are 8 values like

```
'KRB','MBR','GUA','MPR','BOL','BAR','TAL','KAL'.
```

I want to get sum of amount for any specific day by grouping the unit field for 'KRB', 'MBR', 'GUA', 'MPR' AS JGOM and 'BOL', 'BAR', 'TAL', 'KAL' AS OGOM

Comment: ```select Odisha.yymm as yymm, Odisha.total as Odisha,Jharkhand.total as Jharkhand from 
(SELECT YYMM,sum(act_qty) as total from u_pr_mth
where unit in ('BOL','KAL','TAL','BAR') and YYMM=202112) as Odisha, 
(SELECT YYMM,sum(act_qty) as total from u_pr_mth
where unit in ('KRB','MBR','GUA','MPR')and YYMM=202112) as Jharkhand ```

Comment: It's better to execute a raw SQL query for that. Sequelize is to intended for complex aggregation queries